# CakePHP 3 transliterator_transliterate PHP Warning on clean installation

Tags: php, cakephp

I have installed CakePHP 3.4.3 using Composer (their recommended way) and my system meets all of the requirements. Upon installation and basic configuration everything is ticked green.

I've used `bin/bake` to bake the files for 1 very simple table which only has 5 columns: `id, name, url, created, modified`

When I go to insert a new record it's giving the following error message:

**Warning** (2): transliterator_transliterate(): Could not create transliterator with ID &quot;Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [\u0080-\u7fff] remove&quot; (transliterator_create: unable to open ICU transliterator with id &quot;Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [\u0080-\u7fff] remove&quot;: U_INVALID_ID) [**CORE/src/Utility/Text.php**, line **1070**]

I've Googled this but can't find any information I can understand about `transliterator_transliterate()` (never heard of this either).

As the file this is originating from `src/Utility/Text.php` is part of the Cake core I feel it's unwise to delve into this or modify it.

Why is this error being shown, what does it mean, and how can I fix it?

If I switch the debug setting to false in `config/app.php` this hides the message, but I don't feel that's a valid solution as it's complaining about something.

As I say, my system meets all their requirements: PHP 7, centOS, Apache and hasn't had any other errors during installation.

Comment: This  error is thrown by this php function: http://php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php and i think you are facing this issue https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/9697

Comment: @Oliver thanks I'd already read that but don't think there's any solution provided. If some packages need updating I'm unsure why the installation process works without reporting it, especially since it's using Composer to manage dependencies.

Comment: The [**requirement was removed**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/199e535bbdb5c13c2f12b9803327a1403c0a32ac) lately and turned into a suggestion (not a big fan of that decision), as it caused a lot of trouble (so many outdated setups out there :/).

Comment: So what's the solution? To install that package even though it's been removed from `composer.json`? I'm not a fan of this either, if Cake *requires* it to work, why has it been removed as a dependency?!

Comment: The solution is to install/update the library, yes. As I said, I'm not a fan of this not being a requirement anymore, but the suggest description makes it rather clear when this library is needed: "_**The intl PHP library, to use Text::transliterate() or Text::slug()"**_". The fact that it's only these two methods that require it, seems to have been the justification for it being moved to a suggestion.

Comment: @ndm if you want to post that as the answer I'll mark it as accepted, as this is the right solution to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to install/update the ICU library, which seems to be either missing or too old.

The requirement for the library [**was removed**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/10321) from the composer definition lately, and turned into a suggestion, as it caused a lot of trouble for many people with outdated setups. While removing requirements isn't ideal, the fact that only two methods in the core require it seems to have been the justification for it being moved to a suggestion.

The suggest description makes it rather clear when this library is needed:

> The intl PHP library, to use Text::transliterate() or Text::slug()

However it doesn't make any statements regarding the required version, which is something that surely could be improved.